# Android: Shape detection with JavaCV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, javacv, edge-detection

I am new to JavaCV. I am trying to detect largest rectangle in image and outline it with color over original image. I am posting code below which I have tried but it is not working. I am getting `edgeDetectedImage` properly. I am getting 4 corner points properly. Just `cvDrawLine` is not working. Please Help if I am missing anything:

`OnClick` of button I am processing image and showing it again on `ImageView`.
In `onClickListener` of button:

```
if ((new File(path + "trial.jpg")).exists()) {
   opencv_core.IplImage originalImage = opencv_imgcodecs.cvLoadImage(path + "trial.jpg", opencv_imgcodecs.CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
   opencv_core.IplImage iplImage = opencv_imgcodecs.cvLoadImage(path + "trial.jpg", opencv_imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
   opencv_core.IplImage edgeDetectedImage = applyCannyRectangleEdgeDetection(iplImage, 80);
   opencv_core.CvSeq largestContour = findLargestContour(edgeDetectedImage);
   opencv_core.CvPoint[] cvPoints = new opencv_core.CvPoint[4];
   for(int i=0; i<largestContour.total();i++)
   {
     opencv_core.CvPoint cvPoint = new opencv_core.CvPoint(cvGetSeqElem(largestContour, i));
     cvPoints[i] = cvPoint;
   }
   cvDrawLine(originalImage, cvPoints[0], cvPoints[1], opencv_core.CvScalar.YELLOW, 10, 10, 10);
   cvDrawLine(originalImage, cvPoints[1], cvPoints[2], opencv_core.CvScalar.YELLOW, 10, 10, 10);
   cvDrawLine(originalImage, cvPoints[2], cvPoints[3], opencv_core.CvScalar.YELLOW, 10,10, 10);
   cvDrawLine(originalImage, cvPoints[3], cvPoints[0], opencv_core.CvScalar.YELLOW, 10, 10,10);
   opencv_imgcodecs.cvSaveImage(path + "img1.jpg", originalImage);
                    if ((new File(path + "img1.jpg").exists())) {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path + "img1.jpg"));
                    }
                }
```

Method applyCannyRectangleEdgeDetection(IplImage, int):

```
private opencv_core.IplImage applyCannyRectangleEdgeDetection(opencv_core.IplImage iplImage, int percent) {
    opencv_core.IplImage destImage = downScaleImage(iplImage, percent);
    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat converterToMat = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat();
    Frame grayImageFrame = converterToMat.convert(destImage);
    opencv_core.Mat grayImageMat = converterToMat.convertToMat(grayImageFrame);
    GaussianBlur(grayImageMat, grayImageMat, new opencv_core.Size(5, 5), 0.0, 0.0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    destImage = converterToMat.convertToIplImage(grayImageFrame);
    cvErode(destImage, destImage);
    cvDilate(destImage, destImage);
    cvCanny(destImage, destImage, 20, 55);
    return destImage;
}
```

Method downScaleImage(IplImage, int)

```
private opencv_core.IplImage downScaleImage(opencv_core.IplImage srcImage, int percent) {
    opencv_core.IplImage destImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize((srcImage.width() * percent) / 100, (srcImage.height() * percent) / 100), srcImage.depth(), srcImage.nChannels());
    cvResize(srcImage, destImage);
    return destImage;
}
```

Method findLargestContour(IplImage)

```
private opencv_core.CvSeq findLargestContour(opencv_core.IplImage edgeDetectedImage) {
    opencv_core.IplImage foundContoursOfImage = cvCloneImage(edgeDetectedImage);
    opencv_core.CvMemStorage memory = new opencv_core.CvMemStorage().create();
    opencv_core.CvSeq contours = new opencv_core.CvSeq();
    cvFindContours(foundContoursOfImage, memory, contours, Loader.sizeof(opencv_core.CvContour.class), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new opencv_core.CvPoint(0, 0));
    int maxWidth = 0;
    int maxHeight = 0;
    opencv_core.CvRect contr = null;
    opencv_core.CvSeq seqFound = null;
    opencv_core.CvSeq nextSeq;
    for (nextSeq = contours; nextSeq != null; nextSeq = nextSeq.h_next()) {
        contr = cvBoundingRect(nextSeq, 0);
        if ((contr.width() >= maxWidth) && (contr.height() >= maxHeight)) {
            maxHeight = contr.height();
            maxWidth = contr.width();
            seqFound = nextSeq;
        }
    }
    opencv_core.CvSeq result = cvApproxPoly(seqFound, Loader.sizeof(opencv_core.CvContour.class), memory, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(seqFound) * 0.1, 0);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this should be in comments but I don't have enough reputation. What I can see from your code is that the canny is applied on a downscaled image and so is the contour. You are drawing the lines on the original image (which isn't downscaled by percent) so naturally it wouldn't look correct (if it isn't looking correct but something is being drawn). Otherwise, you should mention the color space of the image, it doesn't matter for drawing but does for canny.

Comment: I am taking points from downscaled image and drawing on image. All the operations downscalling and canny was done to get those 4 corner points. And using those points I am drawing lines on original image. What you are saying according to that though dimensions will not proper on original image but atleast something should be drawn on image. In my case here, Nothing is drawn on image.

Comment: Can you post the image and the corner points? If not, have you verified the coordinates of the corners of the rectangle with the image?

Comment: Because from your code it looks like the contours are being extracted from an image which is 0.8 the size of original image, which you are drawing on. Also, what version of OpenCV are you using?